# iPhone: Find UITableViewCell using a UILabel

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsstring

I have a UITableView that has about 20 cells.  Each has a UILabel within, and I need to search and find the cell that has the label @"Test".

Is there a way to loop through the cells and search for the NSString @"Test"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You should not inspect the table view cells. Instead you should look in your *data source* that is providing the contents of those labels.